# Using map function for array of string

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue where I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm passing array of strings (URLs) to a component and try render Images from those URLs by using the map function but what I'm doing seems to break the array.

```
function Board(props) {
  let images = props.images.map((imgUrl, index) => {
    return <img key={index} src={imgUrl} alt="img"></img>;
  });
  console.log(images);

  return (
    <div className="Board">
      <p>Board</p>
      {images}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm probably missing something obvious so thanks in advance

Comment: what you've done look fine -> what's the actual error or problem you are getting?

Comment: The array images is empty after I iterate over it although props.images does actually have a list of URLs

Comment: so if you log out `props.images` it matches the following format?: `['example.com/image.jpg', ...]`? it seems weird that you `images` array would be empty if `props.images` was not empty

Comment: this doesnt make any sense. can you post a codesandbox? why and where do you iterate the `images` array and why would you do that?

Comment: This is the sandbox but weirdly enough it behaves differently https://5zhzo.csb.app/
This time images is always empty although the request returns data

Comment: ok updated my answer. the problem is in your `useEffect`. you need to use async/await.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but that doesn't seem to solve it. As mentioned on my local machine I was lucky enough to get the response into images in the first place but only after calling map was it empty

Comment: ok so we need a true codesandbox in order to alter the code and debug it and not to try to "decompile" it :)

Comment: Isn't that the case with the link above? How can I share the real codesandbox?

Comment: check my updated answer with a codesandbox link that solves your problem. it is not correct to use in such a way these variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing your url, the problem is here

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(API)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => data.forEach((entry) => images.push(entry.download_url)));
  });
console.log(images);
```

images will always be empty. You need to use async/await

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await fetch(API)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => data.forEach((entry) => images.push(entry.download_url)));

      console.log(images);
      images = images.map((imgUrl, index) => {
        return <img key={index} src={imgUrl} alt="img"></img>;
      });
    };
 
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

But there is another problem. You are using a variable not stored in local state which will be lost after next render.

Please see this codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-wood-0r3kw

Initiate your array as

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

and then update the images array inside the useEffect. This is the correct way.

Comment: your bottom one has an error because it will try to render a function as you are not calling it